# Overlap in date range grouped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

How can i know if two rows have overlap in their date range??

Input Dataframe:

| A | B | Start | End | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | 2022-01-15 | 2022-02-15 | 2021-05-17 |
| A1 | B1 | 2021-07-15 | 2021-10-17 | 2021-05-17 |
| A1 | B1 | 2021-07-30 | 2021-10-02 | 2021-05-16 |
| A1 | B2 | 2022-01-01 | 2023-01-01 | 2021-05-17 |
| A1 | B2 | 2021-06-02 | 2021-06-04 | 2021-05-16 |
| A2 | B3 | 2021-05-10 | 2021-05-12 | 2021-05-17 |
| A2 | B3 | 2021-04-10 | 2021-06-12 | 2021-05-16 |
| A2 | B4 | 2021-06-02 | 2021-06-04 | 2021-05-17 |

I want to know how I could identify if there is overlap between two rows of the same group (A and B). For example in rows 0, 1 and 2 they belong to the same group (A1 and B1) but there is only overlap between rows 1 and 2 since they share a part of the date range and therefore what I want is to keep the row that has the highest timestamp if there is overlap. But for example in rows 3 and 4, although they belong to the same group (A1 and B2) since there is no overlap between their dates, I want to keep both dates. How could it be done?

Expected Dataframe:

| A | B | Start | End | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | 2022-01-15 | 2022-02-15 | 2021-05-17 |
| A1 | B1 | 2021-07-15 | 2021-10-17 | 2021-05-17 |
| A1 | B2 | 2022-01-01 | 2023-01-01 | 2021-05-17 |
| A1 | B2 | 2021-06-02 | 2021-06-04 | 2021-05-16 |
| A2 | B3 | 2021-05-10 | 2021-05-12 | 2021-05-17 |
| A2 | B4 | 2021-06-02 | 2021-06-04 | 2021-05-17 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

1. Optionally convert dates to datetime if not already in datetime

```
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'])
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End'])
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
```

2. Sort values to facilitate date comparison between consecutive rows

```
df = df.sort_values(['A', 'B', 'Start', 'End'])
```

3. Set group number within the same `A` and `B` for non-overlapping date ranges:  By comparing `Start` date in a sorted row is larger than `End` date of previous row (this will be non-overlapping date range).  All group numbers are relative to within same groups of `A` and `B`.

```
group = (df['Start'] >  df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['End'].shift()).groupby([df['A'], df['B']]).cumsum()
```

4. Group by `A` and `B` and overlapping group number (by newly created `group`) and   get the index for highest `Timestamp` by `idxmax()`.  Use `.loc` to filter for such rows (with highest `Timestamp` in groups) to retain.   Finally `.sort_index()` to restore the sequence of original dataframe before sorting.

```
df.loc[df.groupby([df['A'], df['B'], group])['Timestamp'].idxmax()].sort_index()
```

**Result:**

```
    A   B      Start        End  Timestamp
0  A1  B1 2022-01-15 2022-02-15 2021-05-17
1  A1  B1 2021-07-15 2021-10-17 2021-05-17
3  A1  B2 2022-01-01 2023-01-01 2021-05-17
4  A1  B2 2021-06-02 2021-06-04 2021-05-16
5  A2  B3 2021-05-10 2021-05-12 2021-05-17
7  A2  B4 2021-06-02 2021-06-04 2021-05-17
```

Answer (score -1):

Panda arrays will be of your help
And it goes like this... array(data[, dtype, copy])...

For more info read docs.... I am still looking for stable answer for this.

[Panda docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/arrays.html)