# Irregular Overlapped Time Series with Total Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, time-series

I have a time series that look like this one:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''
id,start,end,value
1,2021-01-01,2021-03-31,1000
1,2021-01-01,2021-06-30,2000
1,2021-01-01,2021-12-31,5000
2,2021-01-01,2021-02-01,100
2,2021-02-02,2021-05-04,200
2,2021-01-01,2021-08-24,1000
'''))
```

It's possible to have irregular steps and they may overlap, but the value is a summation. And I need to transform it in the smallest possible time intervals by id without overlapping, discounting the overlapped values. The output to that time series would look like this:

```
output = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''
id,start,end,value
1,2021-01-01,2021-03-31,1000
1,2021-04-01,2021-06-30,1000
1,2021-07-01,2021-12-31,3000
2,2021-01-01,2021-02-01,100
2,2021-02-02,2021-05-04,200
2,2021-05-05,2021-08-24,700
'''))
```

I tried to adapt this [Overlap in date range grouped dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68362079/overlap-in-date-range-grouped-dataframe) to my problem, but without success.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What would a the output of the following rows be pd.read_csv(StringIO('''id,start,end,value\n2,2021-01-01,2021-02-01,100\n2,2021-01-15,2021-03-01,200'''))

Comment: At this case there is not information to well divide the data so we could drop one line, or add a flag.